# How to return a json with array Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I do have a table with data like this

```
Product

id     |    name   |     day    |    time
1      |    prod1  |     MON    |    08:30
2      |    prod1  |     MON    |    09:30
3      |    prod1  |     TUE    |    10:30
4      |    prod2  |     WED    |    05:30
5      |    prod3  |     MON    |    11:30
```

how do I return it in POSTMAN like this:

```
prod1 {
     "MON" : [
          08:30,
          09:30
      ],
     "TUE" : [
          10:30
      ]
}
```

Comment: take a look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources

Comment: You need to manipulate the `Product` data in the Controller that's handling this request, then send it back using a standard response, like `response()->json(["data" => $data]);`, etc. That being said, what's the error you're getting? Have you actually tried this? Please include your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one:

```
$products = Product::all();
$jsonOutput = [];

foreach($products as $product){
   $jsonOutput[$product['day']][] = $product['time'];
}

return response()->json($jsonOutput);
```

Comment: Can I do that using this? 


$time_date = DB::table('product_time'>select('product_time')->where('product_id', '=', $product_id)->get();